# Pushing to a remote branch (failed to update ref)

Tags: git, repository, push, branch, bitbucket

I have a remote repository with a feature/initital-change branch. Now I want to push some files to this remote branch from my local feature/initital-change branch.

I went through a few posts on pushing to remote branches and tried out a few methods but I am still getting the same error. After adding and committing, I get the following for git status.

```
Sakibs-MacBook-Pro:BluFireLabs SakibArRahman$ git status
On branch feature/initial-change
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/feature/initial-change' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

But when I push, I get the following:

```
Sakibs-MacBook-Pro:BluFireLabs SakibArRahman$ git push origin feature/initial-change
Counting objects: 255, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (141/141), done.
Writing objects: 100% (255/255), 6.57 MiB | 1.88 MiB/s, done.
Total 255 (delta 49), reused 13 (delta 5)
remote: error: Cannot update the ref 'refs/heads/feature/initial-change': unable to create directory for logs/refs/heads/feature/initial-change: No such file or directory
To git@bitbucket.org:bluefirelabs/fire-voice-droid.git
 ! [remote rejected] feature/initial-change -> feature/initial-change (failed to update ref)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@bitbucket.org:bluefirelabs/fire-voice-droid.git'
```

Any idea on how I can fix this or what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem is on the remote (i.e., on `bitbucket.org`) and must be fixed there.  How to do that, with whatever tools bitbucket gives you, I do not know.

Comment: I was also seeing this error and it was to do with premissions in my Git bare repo ref/heads folder not being set correctly.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This can happen when two branches are created, one with a slash `/` and one without a slash, where the branch without the slash is the prefix of the other branch.

### Example

Consider these two valid branch names:

- `feature`
- `feature/initial-change`

When you fetch these branches from the remote to your local machine the `feature` branch is represented as a file and the `feature/initial-change` branches is represented as a directory named `feature` and a file named `initial-change`. Your OS cannot create a file and directory of the same name:

- `logs/refs/heads/feature`
- `logs/refs/heads/feature/initial-change`

### Workaround

The workaround would be to delete the `feature` branch in this case:

```
git push --force origin :feature
```

Comment: This problem can also appear under Windows with upper and lower case differences. E.g. checkout "feature/myticket" and on other side it is "feature/MYTICKET".

Comment: God bless you. You saved my day :)