# Git Push Unable to Create Directory Error

Tags: git, macos, bitbucket, git-flow

When I try to push a branch that has a slash `/` such as used commonly in git flow I get the following error:

```
(env)➜  api git:(release/0.15) git push --set-upstream origin release/0.15
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: Cannot update the ref 'refs/heads/release/0.15': unable to create directory for logs/refs/heads/release/0.15: No such file or directory
 ! [remote rejected] release/0.15 -> release/0.15 (failed to update ref)
```

This only happens when a branch contains a slash. Looking at the error `logs/refs/heads/release/0.15` should be `.git/logs/refs/heads/release/0.15` right? Or is something else happening here?

Using:

```
git version 2.9.2
/usr/local/bin/git
Mac
BitBucket Remote
```

I have found a similar issue on stackoverflow [git push failing for certain branch names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36853142/git-push-failing-for-certain-branch-names) However, the server remote is BitBucket and I don't have control over that so it does not help me and does not answer my question :)

What I have tried:

Changed `logallrefupdates = false` same error. Checked permissions locally no issues found for the user. There are not hidden files or directories called logs in the root of the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To anyone else having this issue it was a problem on BitBucket that had to be resolved by support. I found problem here https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/9288/cannot-reuse-an-old-branch-prefix-as-a

In a nutshell, BitBucket had a reference to an old branch I deleted, they remove this and it worked again.